# How is the dV/dt of the controller voltage constant?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, powermosfet

Theory of operation: 
When the switch is turned on, R1 feeds voltage to the FET gates, which will be clamped by the zener diode.
Initally, the controller (-) will be at the same voltage as controller (+).
As the FETs turn on, the controller (-) line starts to pull down, causing current flow through the capacitor.
The dV/dt of the controller voltage will be constant to match the zener current. This will cause the current flowing into the capacitors of the controller to be constant during the precharge. Once the controller is fully on, current ceases to flow through C1 and the gate voltage climbs to 12v. Turning the switch off shorts the gate, immediately turning off the FETs and slowly charging C1.[image]

I request you to let me know how the dV/dt of the controller voltage is constant. Also a brief explanation of this circuit would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a so-called Miller Integrator, a capacitor feeding back from the output to the input of an inverting amplifier. The zener diode has nothing to do with the inrush limiting.

When the switch is initially turned on, current flows through R1, raising the voltage on the gates, charging C1, whose other end Vcont- is held at Vpack+ through the load.

Once the voltage on the gates gets to Vgs(thresh), the FETs start to turn on, and the voltage on cont- begins to fall. This fall, transmitted through C1, would tend to lower the gate voltage and turn them off again, so you can see it's negative feedback.

To a first approximation, what happens now is that Vgs stays more or less constant while Vcont- falls. As Vgs is constant(ish), so the voltage across R1 stays constant(ish), so the rate at which C1 charges, that is the rate at which Vcont- falls, is similarly constant. This is the dV/dt your source refers to.

Eventually, Vcont- reaches Vpack- and so can't fall any further, and now Vgs rises, until limited for Vgs(max) safety by the zener diode.

The feedback capacitance between drain and gate of a FET, and the collector  and base of a BJT, is the most significant impediment to operating them quickly, this effect was first described by Miller. Enhancing that capacitance is a simple way to slow things down further.